# Question regarding equation in the multinominal distrubution of the exponential family

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, multinomial-distribution

So this question is regarding to some notes i read in the book Machine learning and pattern recognition in chapter 2 in the section exponential family.

First they state:
[image: So they stated the that it take this form]

So then they derive this which i understand.

[image]
[image]
The part marked with the arrows is what dont understand. It dont think it is clear from the equation that $\sum_{k=1}^{M} x{_k}=1 $ which must be true for the first equation. The second equation (2.211) i dont understand at all.

Comment: This is a subtle thing, but did you notice in the first arrow that the limit of the sum changed from $M$ to $M-1$?  In particular, it's the sum of all $M$ $x_k$ that equals $1,$ not just the sum of the first $M-1$ of them (as you have written). The second arrow invokes the most basic property of the logarithm: it converts multiplication to addition (and therefore division to subtraction).

Comment: Yes @whuber i should have M and i got it now why it equals found it further back in the book. Thanks for the tip on logarithms i saw it now why it work according to the basic rules.